# If $f:X\to Y$ is an injective-continuous function on $X$, show that every $U \subseteq X$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be any metric space and $(Y,p)$ be the discrete metric space. If $f:X\to Y$ is an injective-continuous function on $X$, show that every $U \subseteq X$ is open.

**Definition.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A set $A \subseteq X$ is said to be *open* if for all $a \in A$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq A$.

**My Attempt:**

Let $U \subseteq X$ be given. We want to show that $U$ is open in $X$, that is, to show that for all $x \in U$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq U$.
Since $f$ is continuous on $X$, say, at $u \in X$, then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x \in X$ with $d(x,u)<\delta$, we have $p(f(x),f(u))<\epsilon$. So, for $\epsilon=1$, we have $p(f(x),f(u))<1$, which implies that $f(x)=f(u)$, which gives $x=u$, since $f$ is injective. Hence, for all $x \in U$, we can pick $\delta>0$ such that
$$B(x,\delta)=B(u,\delta)=\{u\} \subseteq U.$$
Thus, $U$ is open, as desired. $\Box$

Does this approach correct?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It is correct but dual use of $\epsilon$ makes it confusing. You should change $\epsilon$ to $\delta$ in the second line of you attempt.